# Panel is not getting visible on clicking of radiobuttonlist using Jquery

Tags: jquery, .net

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="cboVisibility" CssClass="Normal" runat="server"    
RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">Check-In Date</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Book Date</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">Other Date</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSUCCValidity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var panel = $("<%=Panel3.ClientID %>");        
    $("[id*=Panel2] #cboVisibility input:radio").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "2")
            panel.show();
        else
            panel.hide()
    });
});
```

I have a radiobuttonlist inside a panel.
On click of any option of radio button list , I want to show hide another panel.
My code is  shown above
Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
$("[id*=Panel2] #cboVisibility input:radio")
```

by

```
$("#<%= cboVisibility.ClientID %> input:radio")
```

`[id*=Panel2]` is not necessary since we have `#<%= cboVisibility.ClientID %>`. Ids must be unique on the page so there is no need to specify context to identify element.

Comment: :No success .
Why are we not taking Panel2 into consideration ?
Because cboVisibility is inside panel2.

Comment: @palak mehta: please add a debugger inside the change handler to see if reaches that code. Added explanation about why you don't need Panel2.

Comment: :Even after writing $("#<%= cboVisibility.ClientID %> input:radio") it's not working.